# returning data in other language if one of them is null

Tags: php, laravel

I want to return in another language if selected doesnt have code. For example i only have translation in english, and when i visit same page in russian, but russian translation is null i want that it will return me english page with translation, here's my controller:

```
public function index()
{    


$tikrinam =LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();  

$greece = DzongJuan::where('code', "$tikrinam")->first();

if (is_null($greece)) {
    return $greece->where('code' != null) ;

}

 return view('dzong')->with('data', $greece);        

 }
```

Comment: there is a global function trans() in laravel for that...you just need to make a file name.php inside resources/lang/{language_that_you_want}/

Comment: im using dimsav translatable and im returning translations from database

Comment: OK... IMHO you don't need that. But that is just me.